# Is there a way to return C++ datatypes as a variable?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm wondering whether I could do something like:

```
return int
```

So I don't want to return a variable of type int, but the datatype int itself.

In case you're wondering whether this could be useful: I like to convert HDF5-datatypes to normal C++ datatypes. So I like to have method or hash-table that returns me the C++ datatype for any given HDF5-datatype.

Comment: No it's not possible, but you can return a *value* that says that it's an `int`. Read more about e.g. enumerations.

Comment: That sounds like a XY-problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve? The closest I can think of is having a `typedef`.

Comment: How would you declare a function that returns that? What would its return type be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Variable" is a specific term in C++ and not what you're looking for. That said, the answer is yes, but it requires some typing:

```
template<typename T>
class HDF2CPP { };

template<>
class HDF2CPP<H5::IntType> { using type = int };
template<>
class HDF2CPP<H5::StrType> { using type = std::string };
// ...
```

For any given HDF type `T`, `HDF2CPP<T>::type` will give you the corresponding C++ type from the list above.

Answer (score 0):

To my best guess I gather you are getting value and its HDF5 data type (either from file or DB etc.) and you want to assign the value to its appropriate data type in c++.

Unfortunately there is no shortcut to do this as you appears to be thinking. General practice is to form a structure with member types mapped to each column type and assigning incoming data after appropriate conversion.

HDF5 data types and its associated C type is given [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/11_Datatypes.html).

Then your code in C might be something similar to this:

```
struct
{
    char MyChar;
} MyRecord;

if (strcmp (strDataType, "H5T_NATIVE_CHAR") == 0)
    MyRecord.MyChar = strValue[0];
```

This is at very basic. To enhance and make it in C++, you can use operator overloading to make it C++ ish.